# show image files that i record on frame1 show on frame2 in Glade with Python

Tags: python, glade

I have created a home camera appication using Glade3.22.1 with Gtk3.0 and python3.6.7

I have image file that i capture in my app frame1 on Desktop. I want to show this file on my app frame2

This link xml and python file

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1keZ6lKWJ_eGips13-xY4jnr_DC6PKoxK?usp=sharing

"This image file on Desktop"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGG8b.png)

This result i want[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9oDg.png)

Comment: Hello! Could you add the relevant part of the code in the question? Also, did you try anything to achieve your goal? If so, please share your efforts.

Comment: I can get image path but i don't know how I can add images to the frame. @Valentino

Comment: Have a look at [Gtk.Clipboard](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clipboard.html?highlight=image)

Comment: @nook Are you looking for a [`GtkIconView`](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iconview.html)?

Answer (score 0):

My designing thoughts: create
a) 1 label at the top
b) one big field below.. 6 columns
1 row image fields
1 row label file names
1 row image..
..
1 row label file names
in total 61 fields (30 image fields, 30 label file name, 1 label at the top)